# Типы клонирования в c# — Поверхностное и неполное(не считая глубокого)?

Tags: c#

Автор видео курса который я смотрю - сначала говорил что, существует два типа клонирования - поверхностное и глубокое - тут мне все понятно. Но в конце, итог темы - он уточняет, что существует три типа клонирования: поверхностное клонирование, глубокое клонирование и неполное клонирование.
Вот в чем мой вопрос: чем отличается поверхностное и неполное клонирование?

Comment: что за курс? Неполное вполне может копировать не все поля/свойства

Comment: Площадка ITVDN курс C# Essential Урок 16 время 1.00.44 сек

Comment: А что такое «неполное копирование»? Никогда не слышал этого термина.

Comment: @VladD, ой-вэй, это еще и платное.

Comment: Так и я о чем...

Comment: @BadCats, Без контекста того, как и о чем было сказано ничего нельзя сказать. Добавь в вопрос конкретную цитату. либо стоит обратиться с вопросом к авторам курса.

Comment: сейчас кину ссылку на ПОЛНОЕ видео

Comment: @BadCats: Вы бы лучше процитировали нужный кусок текста. Смотреть часовое видео вряд ли всем захочется.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B605djhCYgF_dmt6cUJEeUpJcHc

Comment: Нет необходимости смотреть часовое видео - посмотрите пожалуйста фрагмент 55.00-1.02

Comment: там как раз и контекст будет и пример кода

Comment: @VladD, там речь про [MemberwiseClone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx). В мсдне кстати так и написано - что возвращает неполную копию

Comment: @BadCats, там и объяснение есть. что неполное - это когда этим методом. который не запускает ни конструктор, и не делает глубокое копирование

Comment: но,если неполное это с помощью - MemberwiseClone(), что тогда считается поверхностным ? я имею ввиду в чем между ними разница?

Comment: @BadCats, там на 42-43 минутах он объясняет почему: в некоторых случаях этот метод создает глубокую копию, а в некоторых - нет.

Comment: я пересмотрел 42-43 минуту и получается, что неполное клонирование это что то между поверхностным и глубоким?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49156/discussion-between-grundy-and-badcats).

Comment: Также задам этот вопрос на сайте курса

Comment: @BadCats: Посмотрел видео в промежутке 0:55 - 1:00. Не услышал определение частичного клонирования. (И кстати, видео совершенно ужасно! Автор жевал 5 минут тот факт, что `MemberwiseClone` не вызывает конструктор. Достаточно было сказать один раз, потратить на это 15 секунд максимум.)